# Vertically center a loader using tailwindCSS with Laravel Nova dashboard

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have an empty page, and I want to display a loader before redirecting.

```
 <template>
    <span class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen ">
        <atom-spinner
            :animation-duration="1000"
            :size="160"
            :color="'#1f6492'"
        />
    </span>
</template>

<script>
import {AtomSpinner} from 'epic-spinners'

export default {
    props: [
        'card',
    ],
    components: {
        AtomSpinner
    },

    mounted() {
    },
}
</script>
```

If I do that, the `h-screen` class will take the screen size, without taking the header size, and the margins. So, at the end, it will not be centered vertically.

If I had a way to fill my screen with the , I could do it easily

How should I do to center the loader in the center of the screen ?

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you fork one of these? https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/tailwindcss and share the link.

Comment: I forked it but it is React not Vue, and I can't figure out how to make it work :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A small piece of inline CSS may do the trick:

```
<span class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center" style="height:calc(100% - 60px);">
  <atom-spinner
    :animation-duration="1000"
    :size="160"
    :color="'#1f6492'"
  />
</span>
```

The `60px` value should be adjusted to match the height of the header.

There may be a better way, but assuming that you don't have access to the parent element that wraps the header and the content area, I can't recall a Tailwind class that can manage this.

Comment: yep, it did the trick ! I had to add !important so that it work.